# SonarQube rule changes approval

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to make approval step after rules disabling/changing, for example user make some changes, and after that it needs Security manager approval?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please use 10 minutes to learn how to make a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube does not offer this feature out of the box. You should consider giving the "Administer Quality Profile" permission only to "Security managers".